# Javadoc - Values of constant fields not displaying properly

Tags: java, javadoc, java-9

I was creating docs for one of my projects and I run into a problem with certain characters not displaying properly in the Constant Field Values section. Those letters are "š,č,ć,ž,đ" in my case.

Here's my simple code sample:

```
 /**
 * _insert MainClass doc ščšđčžćđš_
 * 
 * @author Bob
 */
public class MainClass {
    private static final String COOL_LETTERS = "č-š-ć-đ-ž";
    private static final String NORMAL_LETTERS = "a-b-c-d-e";

    /**
     * _insert main method doc đščđščšč_
     * 
     * @param args Arguments đšpšč
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Some normal letters: " + NORMAL_LETTERS);
        System.out.println("Some cool letters: " + COOL_LETTERS);
    }
}
```

After running the javadoc tool, I get the following results:

[image]

and then on clicking the constant fields

[image]

As shown in the first image, special characters in docs for **classes** and **methods** are displayed as they should, but not in **values of string constants**, as shown in second image. They are displayed as */uABCD*

- Project encoding is set to utf8
- I add *-encoding "UTF-8" -docencoding "UTF-8" -charset "UTF-8"* parameters when creating javadoc

Is there a way to get those characters to display properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaDoc has some hardcoded methods to represent the constant expressions in the *constant field table*. This cannot be configured or influenced.

This especially includes printing String expressions by only reproducing printable ASCII characters unmodified. All other characters are reproduced as a Unicode escape.

This will produce Java sourcecode which does not look nice but it does produce the exact same string content (and is less sensitive to source or document encoding). This is probably the reason why it is done.

You cannot avoid this unless you run your own modified version of the Javadoc tool or post-process the generated HTML (possibly in a subclassed Doclet). It is done before the actual Standard Doclet is used for output.

Source: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/langtools/file/ce654f4ecfd8/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javadoc/FieldDocImpl.java#l175